# Who coined the distinction, or at least the terminology of white/black/grey propaganda?

Tags: social-sciences

It's commonly encountered in in textbooks nowadays, e.g. in Jowett & O'Donnell, *Propaganda & Persuasion*. But I'm not sure who coined this distinction. I found it mentioned quite explicitly in a 1949 [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2086855) of Howard [P.] Becker, so it's quite an old typology, but Becker neither seems to claim to have devised nor cites someone else for it...  (In fact, he criticized the notion of "gray" propaganda in that article, which strongly suggests he didn't originate it.)
Becker's Wikipedia [bio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_P._Becker) doesn't mention this typology as a contribution of his, so I'm guessing he wasn't the one who came up with it. He, in fact, writes:

> The division between the two was recognized during the recent war; the Office of War Information (OWI) was restricted to white, and the Office of Strategic Services (OSS) to black.

which suggests it might have originated in the division of labor between these services, but again, that's not terribly clear. So, is there a traceable authoriship or "priority claim" for this typology of propaganda, either in these precise terms or similar ones?

Comment: I think the origins of the term date to at lest before 1941, being often associated with the WWII era British "Political Warfare Executive" and Sefton Delmer. (Both easy to Google, their wikipedia articles' references give further pointers.)